# vmlinuz is missing from my system, how to fix it?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, boot, kernel, linux-kernel

All Linux should come with `vmlinuz` under "`/`", and "`/boot/`" as well. However, my system doesn't have it:

```
% ls -l /vmlinuz* /initrd* /boot/vmlinuz*
ls: cannot access '/vmlinuz*': No such file or directory
ls: cannot access '/initrd*': No such file or directory
ls: cannot access '/boot/vmlinuz*': No such file or directory
```

How can I get all three back?

I tried,

```
apt-get install --reinstall linux-image-generic linux-headers-generic
update-initramfs -u
```

Which should have fixed the problem according to the articles I read, because the actual packages do get reinstalled too:

```
% apt-get install --reinstall linux-image-generic linux-headers-generic 
Preparing to unpack .../linux-headers-generic_4.15.0.20.23_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking linux-headers-generic (4.15.0.20.23) over (4.15.0.20.23) ...
Preparing to unpack .../linux-image-generic_4.15.0.20.23_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking linux-image-generic (4.15.0.20.23) over (4.15.0.20.23) ...
Processing triggers for ureadahead (0.100.0-20) ...
Processing triggers for install-info (6.5.0.dfsg.1-2) ...
Processing triggers for systemd (237-3ubuntu10) ...
Processing triggers for man-db (2.8.3-2) ...
Setting up linux-image-generic (4.15.0.20.23) ...
Setting up linux-headers-generic (4.15.0.20.23) ...
Processing triggers for ureadahead (0.100.0-20) ...
Processing triggers for systemd (237-3ubuntu10) ...
```

but I'm still missing the above three files afterwards.

Comment: Is that after a mistake that deleted those files, or has the system been working without ever having those files? For the second case, I'd suspect the system to be running inside a container (eg a VPS) and then not needing them. Can you tell which case it is?

Comment: Oh, that's a long story @A.B, but since you asked, no, this is a fresh new system which has never been booted. I get it by copying the Ubuntu Live system onto my HD myself. why i'm doing that is another long story, but in brief, having made such copy, both `/vmlinuz` and `/initrd.img` are pointing to the files that are not exist. Thus, in summary, I need to get all three back. Thx.

Comment: I had a similar problem when I was working with a modified squashfs. The problem happened min my case because I passed `-e boot` to `mksquashfs`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
apt-get install --reinstall linux-image-generic
```

Will only reinstall an empty package which doesn't contain actual kernel code, but exists only for the dependencies it pulls.

What should be (re)installed instead to recover missing `/boot` files is the package currently pointed as dependency by [linux-image-generic](https://packages.ubuntu.com/bionic/linux-image-generic). Today that is [linux-image-4.15.0-20-generic](https://packages.ubuntu.com/bionic/linux-image-4.15.0-20-generic). So:

```
apt-get install --reinstall linux-image-4.15.0-20-generic
```

should make the missing files (re)appear. Actually it contains only the minimally needed file: `/boot/vmlinuz-4.15.0-20-generic`. Also reinstalling its dependency [linux-modules-4.15.0-20-generic](https://packages.ubuntu.com/bionic/linux-modules-4.15.0-20-generic) will recover a few other missing files in `/boot` (according to the [list](https://packages.ubuntu.com/bionic/amd64/linux-modules-4.15.0-20-generic/filelist)):

```
/boot/System.map-4.15.0-20-generic
/boot/abi-4.15.0-20-generic
/boot/config-4.15.0-20-generic
/boot/retpoline-4.15.0-20-generic
```

Comment: Please explain again why `linux-image-generic_4.15.0.20.23_amd64.deb` is not OK again please as the comment has been deleted. I.e., in my OP, there is a line, `unpack .../linux-image-generic_4.15.0.20.23_amd64.deb` however it didn't work.

Comment: According to the linked pages, the package linux-image-generic's size once unpacked is 14kb. Following the links, there are *two* files: `/usr/share/doc/linux-image-generic/changelog.gz` and `/usr/share/doc/linux-image-generic/copyright` . On the other hand, the other package, while containing only 3 files, does contain this file: `/boot/vmlinuz-4.15.0-20-generic`: the kernel. This is enough to trigger the rebuild of the associated initramfs file by `update-initramfs -u` . The probable reason it was "lost" when copying the image, is that /boot is a separate partition.

Comment: There's an other (sub-)dependency which contains all kernel modules: linux-modules-4.15.0-20-generic https://packages.ubuntu.com/bionic/amd64/linux-modules-4.15.0-20-generic/filelist . But this was properly copied from the image, so it was not needed to reinstall it. Anyway there are a few /boot files in it (like /boot/System.map*), so I will add it to the answer.

Answer (score 0):

The `apt-get install --reinstall` apparently not helping, so I ended up removing them all first, then installing them again:

```
apt-get --purge remove linux-headers-4.15.0-20 linux-headers-4.15.0-20-generic linux-image-4.15.0-20-generic
apt-get install linux-image-generic linux-headers-generic 

% ls -l /vmlinuz* /initrd* /boot/vmlinuz* /boot/initrd*
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 57592934 Apr 28 16:55  /boot/initrd.img-4.15.0-20-generic
-rw------- 1 root root  8249080 Apr 24 04:42  /boot/vmlinuz-4.15.0-20-generic
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root       33 Apr 28 16:54  /initrd.img -> boot/initrd.img-4.15.0-20-generic
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root       33 Apr 28 16:54  /initrd.img.old -> boot/initrd.img-4.15.0-20-generic
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root       30 Apr 28 16:54  /vmlinuz -> boot/vmlinuz-4.15.0-20-generic
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root       30 Apr 28 16:54  /vmlinuz.old -> boot/vmlinuz-4.15.0-20-generic
```

Maybe it is too heavy-handed, but with `apt-get install --reinstall` not working, I can't think of better ideas.

Answer (score 0):

I solved this problem by booting a live cd, installing the image and headers and copy the missing files back. You can also copy the files from the cd directly in case it's the same kernel. Be aware to recreate the initrd.img by: `update-initramfs -c -k [version]`, don't copy the live-cd version.