# Why dpkg looks for old headers?

Tags: linux-kernel, apt, headers, dpkg, debian-stretch

I am under Debian 9.9 Stretch.

When I want to install new packets with `dpkg -i`, `apt install` or even when I am doing a `apt-upgrade` I got the following error:

```
Processing triggers for initramfs-tools (0.130) ...
update-initramfs: Generating /boot/initrd.img-4.9.0-9-amd64
Added Linux  +  *

Fatal: open /boot/vmlinuz-4.9.0-7-amd64: No such file or directory

run-parts: /etc/initramfs/post-update.d//runlilo exited with return code 1
dpkg: error processing package initramfs-tools (--configure):
 subprocess installed post-installation script returned error exit status 1
Errors were encountered while processing:
 initramfs-tools
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

I don't understand why it looks for 4.9.0-7 since I have 4.9.0-9:

```
 $ uname -a
 Linux my_laptop 4.9.0-9-amd64 #1 SMP Debian 4.9.168-1+deb9u3 (2019-06-16) x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

It seems I also have 4.9.0-8 files:

```
$ ll boot/ | grep vmlinuz
vmlinuz-4.9.0-8-amd64
vmlinuz-4.9.0-9-amd64
```

I tried to install 4.9.0-7 headers (via synaptic package manager) but I ended up with the same error.

It seems I have broke something but I don't know how to fix this (without a full re-installation from scratch, which I'd like to avoid).

Any pointers ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I actually found my answer here: https://superuser.com/a/1318064/329216

It seems the following command did the trick:

```
sudo apt install --reinstall linux-image-4.9.0-7-amd64
```

**[EDIT]** A year later I had similar issue, googled it and found my own post there... Except it did not work this time.
Turns out my `/etc/lilo.conf` was outdated, pointing on old images. I did the following steps:

- remove old images/kernels (do **NOT** remove the one matching `uname -R`) (still got the post-update lilo error at this point)
- manually edit `/etc/lilo.conf` top point on last image
- `sudo liloconfig -u`
- `sudo lilo`
- reboot
- `sudo apt dist-upgrade`

Problem solved.